# Flutter/Gradle Fail to Run app after dependecies set for audioplayers

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

I used audioplayers before without a problem but i'm facing some issues in a new project just for tests, the error syntax is as follows:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Src\Flutter\Flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 367

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Failed to apply plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':path_provider'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

When I remove the audioplayers dependecies from the pubspec file everything works as it should, my pubscpec.yaml looks like this:

```
name: runner
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  audioplayers: ^0.17.0

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
    
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
```

I did some research on gradle versions and stuff, but didnt help much, i'm really clueless about the problem.

My %\runner\android\build.gradle file show the versions as it goes.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

And the %\runner\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties gives me the following version:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

And finally the line 367 from C:\Src\Flutter\Flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle, which the first block of code in this post with the error syntax was complaining about

```
    pluginProject.dependencies {
        implementation dependencyProject
```

Before I forget, that's what I get with 'flutter doctor -v'

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-8.0.pre.340, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.630], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 1.24.0-8.0.pre.340 at C:\Src\Flutter\Flutter
    • Framework revision 7a3a29e71f (4 days ago), 2020-11-20 17:24:58 -0800
    • Engine revision 23a8e027db
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-62.0.dev)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • ASUS A001D (mobile) • K8AXB600B869PNE • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more dependency

dependencies:
provider: ^4.3.2+2

in pubspec.yaml file..

Comment: sorry, but it didn't help, i got dependecies like

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  audioplayers: ^0.17.0
  provider: ^4.3.2+2

and the error persisted

Comment: please show the imports of all the files that you have used. so that i can tell you what dependencies you still need. or show the code..

Answer (score 0):

before this "audioplayers: ^0.17.0"  u should click two space

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).